# How can I achieve this pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I need to replicate this pattern (the distorted white, pink and red circles spirals) I have tried a few ways but wasn't satisfied. I am using Photoshop currently, but I could also do it in Illustrator if it's better.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In illustrator, I'd create a dot grid and play around with effects>Distort and tranform > Free transform, with envelope distort, or with the "map art" feature of the 3d effects. This is a quick 3-minute version I did:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's done in illustrator.

A custom art brush created from circles applied on a circular path with a width profile (thing to thick to thin) added which was then adjusted with the Width Tool.

That's basically it from my point of view, you just need a lot of tweaking to achieve the same effect.